# How to strip blocks out of an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm posting this more as a learning exercise than because I need to change the implementation away from an imperative loop. My question is how would one convert this loop to LINQ? Given an input IEnumerable of bytes which is considered to be in "blocks" of 8 bytes. The output IEnumerable should have any blocks which contain a 0 removed.

Rough Imperative implementation

```
    private static IEnumerable<byte> StripBlocksWithZeroes(IEnumerable<byte> input)
    {
        var stripped = new List<byte>();
        var inputArray = input.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i += 8)
        {
            if (inputArray[i + 0] != 0 &&
                inputArray[i + 1] != 0 &&
                inputArray[i + 2] != 0 &&
                inputArray[i + 3] != 0 &&
                inputArray[i + 4] != 0 &&
                inputArray[i + 5] != 0 &&
                inputArray[i + 6] != 0 &&
                inputArray[i + 7] != 0)
            {
                stripped.Add(inputArray[i + 0]);
                stripped.Add(inputArray[i + 1]);
                stripped.Add(inputArray[i + 2]);
                stripped.Add(inputArray[i + 3]);
                stripped.Add(inputArray[i + 4]);
                stripped.Add(inputArray[i + 5]);
                stripped.Add(inputArray[i + 6]);
                stripped.Add(inputArray[i + 7]);
            }
        }
        return stripped;
    }
```

Comment: You're only doing `stripped.Add(inputArray[i]);`, did you mean to strip off the last 7 bytes of the block?

Comment: Hey you found a bug in my question! Awesome, thanks.

Comment: @Felix, so what did you want to include in the result? The 8 bytes? Can you please fix your question so we can give accurate answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
inputArray.Select((item, index) => new {item, groupIndex = index / 8})
          .GroupBy(x => x.groupIndex)
          .Where(g => g.All(x => x.item != 0))
          //.Select(g => g.First().item)
          .SelectMany(g => g.Select(x => x.item))
```

A bit of explanation:

Tag each item with a groupIndex, taking advantage of integer division, so each contiguous group of 8 will have the same groupIndex.

Group by the group index, so now we have a sequence of sequences.

For each of the inner sequences, make sure it doesn't contain a zero.

Flatten the resulting sequence of sequences back to a single sequence.

Comment: I like the top of your head.

Comment: I'd like to reiterate that this is untested.

Comment: Actually I think the last line should be `.Select(g => g.First())`

Comment: I was about to post almost the same, but you were faster ;)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque : Yes, you're right about the `.First`

Comment: @spender, except that the OP said in the comments that it was a bug in his question ;)

Comment: My psychic powers were obviously flowing strong!

Comment: @spender: apart from the fact that you've originally selected the anonymous type instead of the byte, my magic crystal ball was stronger ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Most psychics talk in vagaries, so definitely above par!

Answer (score 3):

Yet another slightly different version:

```
    return input.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                .GroupBy(x => x.index / 8, x => x.value)
                .Where(g => g.All(value => value != 0))
                .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Point of interest: this code uses [this `GroupBy` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx), that takes an element selector to get rid of the index as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the "integer-division-trick" to group by 8 bytes and check if any of them are 0:

```
private static IEnumerable<byte> StripBlocksWithZeroes(IEnumerable<byte> input)
{
    IEnumerable<byte> stripped = input
        .Select((b, i) => new { Byte = b, Index = i })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 8)
        .Where(g => g.All(x => x.Byte != 0))
        .SelectMany(g => g.Select(x => x.Byte))
        .ToList();
    return stripped;
}
```